# IIS 7 Rewrite web.config serverVariables directive not working in sub folder

Tags: iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="IP Correction">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="{HTTP_X-Forwarded-For}"/>
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works perfectly on the root of my site, however, the rule isn't being triggered in any of the sub folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.  The problem was in this line of code

```
<action type="None" />
```

You have to specify the rewrite action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="IP Correction">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="{HTTP_X-Forwarded-For}" replace="true"/>
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the action to "Rewrite" since you're not trying to rewrite the URL. However, URL Rewrite has a bug where it won't always execute for default documents. See my answer below for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue and created an IHttpModule to address it, which you can [find here](https://gist.github.com/winzig/ee57e559341a2a92d8ee7bc0daa1304a). URL Rewrite seems to have a bug where it won't execute on default document requests. The module doesn't have that issue. To implement it on your site, you'd add it to the `<modules>` section of your web.config, or if you want it to run server-wide, to your applicationHost.config.

The relevant bit of code is that you're hooking into HttpApplication's BeginRequest event, and running:

```cs
void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        string headervalue = app.Context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];

        if (headervalue != null)
        {
                Match m = REGEX_FIRST_IP.Match(headervalue);

                if (m.Success)
                {
                        app.Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] = m.Groups[1].Value;
                        app.Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] = m.Groups[1].Value;
                }
        }
}
```

The Regex is `^\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)`. Full code at [the gist](https://gist.github.com/winzig/ee57e559341a2a92d8ee7bc0daa1304a).

If you compiled this code into a class library called HttpModules and put it in your GAC, you could then add this to your `<modules>` section, something like:

`<add name="ClientIP" type="YourLibrary.ClientIP, YourLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00DEADBEEF00" />`