# Using Url Rewrite to change REMOTE_ADDR works for files but not folders

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I have a number of websites that make use of the REMOTE_ADDR server variable to record client IPs for metrics.  In moving the hosting of these sites into a load balanced environment we're now only ever getting the load balancer IP in REMOTE_ADDR.  I'm fully aware of the use of HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and how it works and we do have access to it and my preferred solution is to simply update the applications to use it.

However, the powers that be here want to avoid having to update all of the websites :(  I'm looking into alternatives in the mean time.

Ultimately this means finding some way of replacing REMOTE_ADDR with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR before the request hits the applications.

I'm trying to get the URL Rewrite 2.0 module working using advice from another acole76's question here:

[IIS 7 Rewrite web.config serverVariables directive not working in sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189445/iis-7-rewrite-web-config-servervariables-directive-not-working-in-sub-folder)

My web.config is practically the same as his:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RemoteHostRewrite">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="4.3.2.1" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm using a hard-coded value 4.3.2.1 here for testing.  I'll eventually replace that with the real value {HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}.

Now, this works absolutely fine if a url contains a file name.  It does not work if the url does not end with a file name.

For example:
mysite.local/default.aspx - works

mysite.local/ - does not work

mysite.local/folder/default.aspx - works

mysite.local/folder/ - does not work

I'm stumped!  Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42709697/650558

Answer (score 0):

you have to set another rule:

```
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/default.aspx" />
```

or whatever your default-page is
otherwise "url" will be empty --> no rule used